# protobuf-net encode DateTime UTC decode ToLocalTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, protobuf-net

Is there a way for protobuf-net to automatically encode DateTime values in UTC but decode with ToLocalTime?

I'm passing messages between systems in different time zone and would like each DateTime property in my DTO' to be serialized as UTC (essentially automatically call ToUniversalTime before encoding) and decode in LocalTime so the systems receiving the messages automatically can operate on the DateTime Properties in LocalTime, so developers don't have to remember calling ToLocalTime on each property for DTO's received over the wire?

Answer (score 1):

For this type of transformation, the usual approach is to have two properties:

```
[ProtoMember(n, ...)]
public DateTime When { get; set; }

public DateTime WhenLocal => When.ToLocal(); // etc
```

The serializer won't care about the one without the attribute. The serializer property could be private if you really really don't want callers using it.

Comment: Thank you - do you have any suggestions how the same could be achieved without making any changes to the models/DTO's?

Comment: @TJF partial classes? extension methods?

Comment: I'd really like this to be handled on the encoding/decoding level. We're using multiple encoding protocols to move our DTO's around and we implemented the DateTime encoding there to care of this for us automatically. We're now looking to expose a protobuf endpoint while using our pre-existing DTO's the same way. Does the protobuf library somehow allow to override serialization/deserializtion behavior for  types?

Comment: @TJF not currently; there will almost certainly be a new API for that in the 3.0 milestone, as the key deliverable there is build-time C# serializer generation. Basically, think `IProtoSerializer<T>` providing custom `Serialize(ProtoWriter writer, in T obj)` and `Deserialize(ProtoReader reader, ref T obj)` methods. This same API would presumably also allow you to inject your own behaviour, although that is merely a happy side-effect, not the primary aim of the new API. I do not currently have an ETA for 3.0